# Nginx: internal error 500 with nodejs stack

Tags: node.js, nginx

So, I'm using nginx nodejs stack for mailgun receive inbound to forward message, and the message passed to my api perfectly.

> But it gives error 500 to mailgun log from nginx, I can't send
>   response.status(200) from node js.

This is nginx error log, just looping.

```
[info] 16904#16904: *87 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac) while SSL handshaking, client: from.mailgun
[info] 16904#16904: *88 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 96.126.100.87 [warn] 24803#24803: *1 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001, client: from.mailgun
[error] 24803#24803: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: from.mailgun
[info] 24803#24803: *1 SSL_write() failed (SSL:) (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: from.mailgun
```

nodejs doesn't give any error log, I have checked many times.

Here's my ssl nginx config ,
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

This is from my server block,

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
# include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show your ssl settings from nginx.conf

Comment: @Qteb thanks for reaching me! I've updated with config, sorry for late reply just get back from work.

Comment: Researching the error line `ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac` took me to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/860010/148942) to a question with the same error, but in an Apache setup.  Have you tried a fresh SSL config from [mozillas config gen](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/)?